# Twitter oEmbed widgets overlap in Safari

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter, safari, oembed

I'm using oEmbed tweets in my application and having an issue with the way they render in Safari.  The tweets are rendering as expected in Firefox and Chrome, but in Safari, the initial render has the tweet widgets overlapping as shown below:

[image]

This is how they are supposed to display and how they render in the other browsers:

[image]

Now, if I resize the width of the window after the tweets render, they pop into place the way they should.  I can't quite figure out why this would be and due to there being no errors, I'm a little stuck.  I'm using this library: https://github.com/arusahni/ngtweet and this is the relevant HTML for my application

```
<div ng-repeat="tweet in updatedTweets | orderBy:'-'" ng-init="getTweetTotals(tweets)" class="twitter-widget">
                        <twitter-widget twitter-widget-id="tweet.id_str" twitter-widget-options="{'width': '300px', 'cards': 'hidden'}">
                        </twitter-widget> 
</div>
```

css for the twitter-widget class:

```
.twitter-widget {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 2px;
  position: relative;
}
```

I also tried wrapping the controller code that loads the tweet array into a $timeout, but that didn't help.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I fixed this.  As far as I can tell, the oEmbed widget was rendering *after* the ng-repeat created the element for each tweet.  So the elements initially had a null width and are staggered as seen in the first image due to the css margin between tweets.  I assumed (wrongfully) that defining the width in the oEmbed options would cover this, but the solution was to define a css width for the container class I created for the tweets.

```
.twitter-widget {
width: 304px; //added a few pixels for the padding in the widget
}
```

This solved the issue.